# NullPointerException with openjdk 6 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, timezone, nullpointerexception, ubuntu-12.04

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 from 10.10.  Since then, I get a NullPointerException in the TimeZone class with openjdk 6.

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-0:00");
```

There is no exception with openjdk 7, nor do my coworkers get an exception with openjdk6.  So it looks like I'm missing some necessary library.

Also, this works just fine: `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")` on my machine with openjdk 6

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve it by complete removing the tzdata-java package and re-installing.  Note that also removed a bunch of openjdk6 packages as well. (I had already tried completely removing and reinstalling the openjdk6 packages without luck).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with DbVisualizer yesterday (NPE on startup), and it turned out that a forum post at http://www.dbvis.com/forum/thread.jspa?messageID=14474 had the solution.

Try running this command to see where your Java timezone files are located:

```
locate GMT | grep java | grep zi
```

In my case, the contents of /usr/share/javazi were symlinks that pointed to the actual files, and many of those symlinks were broken.  I simply re-pointed the symlinks for my timezone to the new file locations, and that got DbViz working for me.  Perhaps something similar will work for you.